# Regular Expression Split Comma Separated Braces, Should Be Easy

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

To all: I have this string:

```
"{1,2,3},{4},{3}"
```

That I want to split to an array like this:

```
    {1,2,3}
    {4}
    {3}
```

The pattern I am using `",\{([^)]*)\},"` is only partially working and giving me an array of:

```
    {1,2,3}
    4
    {3}
```

I am doing this:

```
string[] strs = Regex.Split(string, pattern)
```

I can't figure out what I am missing so that the 2nd value is missing the braces. I've been banging my head against the wall.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex to split:

```
(?<=\}),(?=\{)
```

This matches all commas `,` that are preceded by `}` and have `}` after them.

[RegexHero Demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=ee9dfa9e-d9b5-4926-a94d-0148b9446d36)

Comment: @Sniffer btw, you don't even need to escape the braces. That's only necessary if they'd form a valid quantifier otherwise.

Comment: @m.buettner Thanks for the tip, it is always welcome to get such enlightening feedback.

Comment: @Sniffer I am sorry if I offended you, but reducing clutter from unnecessary escaping is one of the most helpful methods to increase regex readability (imho), so I figured you and/or the OP might like know. I'll remember not to mention it next time.

Comment: @m.buettner I am very very sorry if you felt that I was upset by your comment. On the contrary I was extremely happy because I didn't knew that piece of information, what I meant by saying "it is always welcome to get such enlightening feedback" is exactly that. I love to know these little thinks and I love when people make such helpful and useful comments such as yours. Again I am deeply sad and sorry if you felt that I was insulting you in any way. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use split andd add the pare you've put out:

```
string[] splitted = str.Split("},{");


for(int i = 0; i < splitted.Count ; i++)
{
  if(i != 0)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("{");
  }
  Console.WriteLine(curr[i]);
  if(i != splitted.Count - 1)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "pure Regex" answer is like this:

```
        string str = "{1,2,3},{4},{3}";
        string[] strs =
            Regex.Matches(str, @"({.*?})")
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
                 .ToArray();
```

which is more tolerant of different - or even mixed - separators between the braced groups, such as comma-space or space rather than just a comma.  If your input string is well-defined then this won't be an issue, but I prefer to be able to handle inputs which might come from different sources and might not *quite* conform.